# Issues with SignalR Client in Python 3.12 - 'AuthHubConnection' Object Lacks 'connection_id'

Tags: python, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am currently working on integrating SignalR in Python 3.12 for a project where I need to establish subscriptions with an API. I'm using the signalrcore library for the SignalR client implementation. However, I'm encountering an issue where the 'AuthHubConnection' object seems to lack the 'connection_id' attribute, which is crucial for my application.

Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
import logging
import traceback
from signalrcore.hub_connection_builder import HubConnectionBuilder

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def establish_signalr_connection(api_url, token):
    global connection
    if not token:
        logger.error("No valid token available for SignalR connection.")
        return None

    try:
        logger.info("Attempting to establish SignalR connection...")
        connection = HubConnectionBuilder()\
            .with_url(api_url + "/signalr", options={"access_token_factory": lambda: token})\
            .configure_logging(logging.DEBUG)\
            .with_automatic_reconnect()\
            .build()

        connection.start()
        logger.info("SignalR connection started, checking for connection_id...")
        if hasattr(connection, "connection_id"):
            logger.info(f"Connection ID: {connection.connection_id}")
        else:
            logger.warning("Connection established but no 'connection_id' attribute found.")
        return connection
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error establishing SignalR connection: {e}")
        logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
        return None
```

When I run this code, I receive the following logs:

```
2023-12-21 11:06:11,349 - INFO - Authenticated successfully
2023-12-21 11:06:11,349 - INFO - Attempting to establish SignalR connection...
2023-12-21 11:06:11,783 - INFO - Heartbeat refreshed successfully
2023-12-21 11:06:11,789 - INFO - SignalR connection started, checking for connection_id...
2023-12-21 11:06:11,789 - WARNING - Connection established but no 'connection_id' attribute found.
2023-12-21 11:06:11,789 - INFO - SignalR connection established.
2023-12-21 11:06:11,789 - ERROR - Error subscribing to values: 'AuthHubConnection' object has no attribute 'connection_id'
2023-12-21 11:06:11,789 - INFO - Subscribed to values with request ID: None
```

I would really appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Specifically, I am looking for guidance on:

1. Why the 'connection_id' attribute might be missing from the 'AuthHubConnection' object.
2. Any potential fixes or workarounds to successfully establish a SignalR connection and subscribe to values.

Thanks people!

Based on the SignalR documentation, I anticipated that once the connection is established, I would be able to retrieve the connection_id to proceed with subscriptions.

Comment: Could you kindly check the answer below, if you need further help, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to my code to get the `connection_Id`.

[image]

[image]

```
import logging
from signalrcore.hub_connection_builder import HubConnectionBuilder
import asyncio
import urllib.parse as parse

class SignalRClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hub_connection = None
        self.connection_id = None
        self.connected = False
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("SignalRClient")

    def configure_logging(self):
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

    def on_open(self):
        self.connected = True
        try:
            connection_id = parse.parse_qs(parse.urlparse(self.hub_connection.transport.url).query)['id'][0]
            self.connection_id = connection_id
            self.logger.info(f"Connected with connection ID: {self.connection_id}")
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(f"Error retrieving connection ID: {e}")
        
        self.hub_connection.send("SendGemstoneDetailMessage", [["aa"]])

    def on_close(self):
        self.connected = False
        self.logger.info("Connection closed")

    def on_error(self, data):
        self.logger.error(f"An exception was thrown: {data.error}")

    def connect(self):
        self.configure_logging()
        try:
            self.hub_connection = HubConnectionBuilder() \
                .with_automatic_reconnect({
                    "type": "raw",
                    "keep_alive_interval": 10,
                    "reconnect_interval": 5,
                    "max_attempts": 5
                }) \
                .with_url("https://localhost:7262/mainHub?uid=jason&sid=test&api-key=112233", options={"verify_ssl": False}) \
                .build()

            self.hub_connection.on("ReceiveMessage", self.receive_message)
            self.hub_connection.on_open(self.on_open)
            self.hub_connection.on_close(self.on_close)
            self.hub_connection.on_error(self.on_error)

            self.hub_connection.start()
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(f"Failed to connect to the server: {e}")

    def receive_message(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.info(f"Message received: {args}")

    async def listen_forever(self):
        while True:
            if not self.connected:
                self.logger.warning("Disconnected, attempting to reconnect...")
                self.connect()
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    signalr_client = SignalRClient()
    signalr_client.connect()
    await signalr_client.listen_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```